# Do you automatically change UI design to Flutter code in your field?

Tags: flutter

If you work as a Flutter developer, how do you handle things like UI? Do you modify the code every time there is a little change? Or do you automate it in conjunction with design tools?
I used a plugin "Figma2Flutter", but it seemed quite complicated and I was wondering if you use this method in your field as well.
If the designer wants to move the button a little bit, is it like changing the code even?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no direct way to update the code. The only way to make it easy is by identifying and reusing the component and by applying theme

Comment: So even if there's a slight change, you have no choice but to modify the source code?
I don't want developers to work on simple design changes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about figma2flutter, but from the main.dart file you can define an application theme which will be reflected everywhere in your code. For example colors, fonts, appearance of text fields, etc... https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/design/themes

Comment: So even if there's a slight change, you have no choice but to modify the source code?
I don't want developers to work on simple design changes.